Is there a way to unsubscribe from a Subject of System.Reactive
I am new to System.Reactive and trying to understand how to use this extension for some of the scenarios.
I have basically three components, one is creating the message and the others are the receiver of the message.
public class Messager : IMessager
{
    private readonly Subject<int> _subject = new();
    private readonly List<IDisposable> _disposables = [];
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _subject?.Dispose();
        foreach (var eachDisposable in _disposables)
        {
            eachDisposable?.Dispose();
        }
    }
    public void Emit(int value)
    {
        _subject.OnNext(value);
    }
    public void OnEmit(Action<int> action)
    {
        _disposables.Add(_subject.Subscribe(action));
    }
}

The IMessager inherits IDisposable and the IMessager is registered as Scoped in the Program.cs file.
ComponentOne.razor and ComponentTwo.razor are look exactly like the below code
@inject IMessager _messager;

    <div>
        <span>@value</span>
        <div>
            <MessageCreator/>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    @code {
        private int value;
        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            base.OnInitialized();
            _messager.OnEmit(Action);
        }
    
        private void Action(int value)
        {
            this.value = value;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }

The MessageCreator.razor looks like:
@inject IMessager _messager;

<div>
    <button @onclick="ClickMe">ClickMe</button>
</div>

@code {
    private int count = 0;
    private void ClickMe()
    {
        count++;
        _messager.Emit(count);
    }
}

And they are called in the home.razor
@page "/"

<div>
    <div>
        <ComponentOne/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ComponentTwo/>
    </div>
</div>

If I click the button ClickMe on ComponentOne -> MessageCreator -> ClickMe - this increments the counter to 1. Both the components are updated with the value 1 because both are "subscribing" through OnEmit. Same goes for the ComponentTwo only with a separate instance of MessageCreator.razor.
So here's some of my questions:
Question 1: The IMessager registered with Scoped but when I tried with Transient it does not work, why? (Because ComponentOne.razor and MessageCreator.razor must get the same obejct.. I guess)
Question 2. Is there a way to unsubscribe. Let just say for certain cases the ComponentOne does not want to receive any notification?
Question 3. What I want is that a message generated from clicking on ComponentOne -> MessageCreator -> ClickMe should only receive by ComponentOne but not by ComponentTwo.(or do I have to use something other than Subjct)

If you do not want them reusing the same object you can try creating two interfaces that inherit from IMessager.

@beautifulcoder Yes that is an option but imagine I have 5 different components so now I have to create 5 different interfaces for each.

Factory pattern comes to mind but it's a question of how much pain

@beautifulcoder after all is there is a way to safely unsubscribe from the subject when the component is destroyed. I tried calling Dispose by implementing IDisposable in the component but the behavior was not what I was expecting. Sill figuring it out

Yes, you can unsubscribe as long as they do not share the same instance.
